# Controller action not reading Guid POST from JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Controller action declared as:

```
[Route("api/person")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Person([FromBody] Guid id) { ... }
```

I am posting to it with:

```
POST /api/person HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 747a5d76-398c-e1c7-b948-b276bb24976c

{
    "id": "b85f75d8-e6f1-405d-90f4-530af8e060d5"
}
```

My action is being hit, but the `Guid` that it receives is always a `Guid.Empty` value (ie: it's not getting the value I'm passing it).

Note, this works fine if I use url parameters instead of `[FromBody]`, but I'd like to use the body of the http post instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the id be raw JSON string rather than an object? So just "b85f75d8-e6f1-405d-90f4-530af8e060d5"?

Comment: Also, pass in a string and then TryParse to Guid. I would test this on my machine but my VS is installing.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'm on mobile but will test it out in the morning.

Answer (score 19):

As described in [Web API documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>     bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>     and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>     a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Further in the same article in section **Using [FromBody]** you can see the sample that you can add attribute `[FromBody]` on your parameter in order to bind the value from the request body, just like you did. But here is the catch - sample shows, that in this case request body should contain raw value, not JSON object.

So in your case you have 2 options:

First option is to change your request to provide raw value instead of a JSON object

```
POST /api/person HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 747a5d76-398c-e1c7-b948-b276bb24976c

"b85f75d8-e6f1-405d-90f4-530af8e060d5"
```

Second option is to provide complex object with single property and use it as parameter:

```
public class Request
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/person")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Person([FromBody] Request request) { ... }
```

Comment: You said "First option is to change your request to provide raw value instead of a JSON object", but in the example you give, Context-Type: application/json.

Comment: in second option you still need to provide it with a Guid, which fails again:
{
  "Request": {"Id":"e01b8040-8fd7-4227-a55a-111111111111"}
}